How to specify the schema per table for query with llama_index
When running below script I get this error:

It appears there was an error in the SQL query provided. The correct query should be:
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, w.worked_hours
FROM employees e
JOIN worked_hours w ON e.employee_id = w.employee_id;

When I run this query in e.g. DBVisualizer, it runs perfectly fine, see screenshot. 
The problem seems to be that both table occur in different schemas. I set the schema in SQLDatabase but this is not sufficient. Is it possible to define the tables on schema level, like below?
include_tables=[("employees", schema_1), ("worked_hours", schema_2)]
This is the code i used.
from llama_index.core import SQLDatabase
from llama_index.core.query_engine import NLSQLTableQueryEngine
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


engine = get_engine()
include_tables=["employees", "worked_hours"]
schema = "sch_employee"
sql_database = SQLDatabase(engine=engine, include_tables=include_tables, schema=schema)
query_engine = NLSQLTableQueryEngine(sql_database=sql_database, tables = include_tables, verbose=True)

query = "Give ma a table of all employees and worked hours."
r = query_engine.query(query)
print(r)

